# Why is an array used to compute an index in this MATLAB code?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a question about some MATLAB code. Its name is `lfsrv2` and it works but I can't figure out one line of it. the writer of this code is Mr. Nikesh Bajaj (http://nikeshbajaj.in).

Here is the code:

```matlab
function[seq,c]=LFSRv2(s,t)
%s=initial state of LFSR, you can choose any lenght of LFSR
%Instruction:==========
%Save LFSR.m in your current directory and type following
%on Command window for simulating 5 bit LFSR with tap [5 2]
%--EXAMPLE-------------------
%>>s=[1 1 0 0 1]  
%>>t=[5 2]
%>>[seq c] =LFSRv2(s,t)
%---------------------------
%seq = generated sequence
%c will be matrix containing the states of LFSR raw wise
%
%-----------------------------------------------------------

n=length(s);
c(1,:)=s;
m=length(t);
N = 2^n-2;
for k=1:N
    b(1)=xor(s(t(1)), s(t(2)));
    if m>2
        for i=1:m-2
            b(i+1)=xor(s(t(i+2)), b(i));
        end
    end
    j=1:n-1;
    s(n+1-j)=s(n-j);
    s(1)=b(m-1);
    c(k+1,:)=s;
end
seq=c(:,n)';
```

My question is about the `j` variable. It is obvious that it is an array and for n=16, it holds numbers from 1 to 15.

But at the next line `s(n+1-j)=s(n-j);` I can't understand how an array index for `s`, can be calculated with `n+1-j` because `j` isn't an int, it is an array.

Comment: MATLAB is a *matrix* language. Statements operate on entire matrices.

Comment: There seems to be an end missing at the end of your code

Comment: what's the problem with j being an array in this context? Have you read much of the documentation on indexing? It's pretty straightforward once you do.

Comment: Also, please use a debugger

Comment: @MadPhysicist. actually im a C# programmer and just have 1 year experience in MATLAB so understanding some context like this needs an explanation. thank u i guess i found out the answer.

Comment: This is the first Google result for “matlab indexing”: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html The second example explains indexing with an array.

Comment: The official documentation is also a good place to read: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html — much easier and faster than asking a question on SO for basic stuff like this.

Comment: @CrisLuengo .thank you so much. I learned so much from the your links.

Comment: @Makyen . you are right and i am aware of it. I wrote two lines in my question as comment in the code to introduce the writer of that code but i do not know who deleted that from my question and edited it. i will mention him again and actually i sent an e-mail to him and he answered me openly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example that should clarify how this works:

```matlab
>> a = 1:10

a =  1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10


>> b = [3 4]

b =  3     4


>> a(b) = [1 2]

a =  1     2     1     2     5     6     7     8     9    10
```

Notice that `a(3) == 1` and `a(4) == 2` now.

---

So, in the context of your code, I added a `break` statement in the `for` loop to observe the output only for one iteration. I also added a few display statements to see the contents (ideally you should use the [inbuilt debugger](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html) for this):

```matlab
clc;close all;

s=[1 1 0 0 1];
t=[5 2];
[seq c] =LFSRv2(s,t);

function[seq,c]=LFSRv2(s,t)
    n=length(s);
    c(1,:)=s;
    m=length(t);
    N = 2^n-2;
    for k=1:N
        b(1)=xor(s(t(1)), s(t(2)));
        if m>2
            for i=1:m-2
                b(i+1)=xor(s(t(i+2)), b(i));
            end
        end
        
        j=1:n-1;
        disp("Value of s before change")
        disp(s)
        disp("Value of n+1-j")
        disp(n+1-j)
        disp("Value of n-j")
        disp(n-j)
        disp("Value of s(n+1-j) before change")
        disp(s(n+1-j))
        disp("Value of s(n-j)")
        disp(s(n-j))
        s(n+1-j)=s(n-j);
        disp("Value of s after change")
        disp(s)
        s(1)=b(m-1);
        c(k+1,:)=s;
        break
    end
    seq=c(:,n)';
end
```

Its output was:

```
Value of s before change
     1     1     0     0     1

Value of n+1-j
     5     4     3     2

Value of n-j
     4     3     2     1

Value of s(n+1-j) before change
     1     0     0     1

Value of s(n-j)
     0     0     1     1

Value of s after change
     1     1     1     0     0
```